# What is this partial box with angled arrow icon called?

Tags: microsoft-office, icons

Does this icon have a specific name?

It is formed of a vertical line on the left and a horizontal line along the top, and then an arrow at 45° pointing towards the bottom right - a horizontally reflected uppercase L.

It shows up in the bottom right corner of some sections of the ribbon within Microsoft Office products, including font and alignment.

Clicking it opens additional tools in a dialog window.

[image]

I searched online and I searched microsoft kb as well.

Comment: It would be something like `more settings` or `expanded view`

Comment: Thank You. But is there a Microsoft link which tells me the exact name for this icon?

Comment: Not that I know of. If I knew, the above would've been posted as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a Unicode character for it, but ⇲ is SOUTH EAST ARROW TO CORNER and ⇱ is NORTH WEST ARROW TO CORNER so if it's ever standardised then the smart money is on SOUTH EAST ARROW FROM CORNER

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Office documentation calls this button the "**Dialog Box Launcher**". For example:

- [Change the default font in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-default-font-in-word-2f50603b-9886-47e4-a483-48ac5ab80163)
- [Excel – Enter and format data – Format text in cells](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-text-in-cells-ca112674-a567-4d6f-b5f8-3100aa27f40e)

Comment: "Popout" would be a far more sensible name, but it does appear that Microsoft created their own opaque name. If writing documentation for users, I would recommend including both the official Microsoft name and the name a user is likely to recognize and/or search for.

Answer (score 36):

That is a [Dialog Box Launcher Control](https://developerpublish.com/dialog-box-launcher-in-microsoft-word/).

> **Dialog box launcher in Microsoft Word**
>
> A dialog box launcher is an iconic arrow that activates various options in the ribbon menu of Microsoft Office products.
>
> The dialog box launcher brings up different options depending on the group being used. Clicking on the icon opens a dialog box related to the choices in the menu group.

[image: Dialog Box Launcher Control]

More info here:

- https://developerpublish.com/dialog-box-launcher-in-microsoft-word/
- https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-excel/getting-to-know-ribbon.html
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/76d9f878-6b27-49ff-8c4c-ee008f345cac?redirectedfrom=MSDN
- https://rlbcontractor.com/put-a-dialog-box-launcher-on-your-custom-office-ribbon
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJLjTvsxfg4